# Get audio samples sent to Output Device

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-4, raspbian-lite

I want to get in real-time the audio samples that are sent to the output device (i.e. analog audio or HDMI). Is there any way to read those samples? I'm running the latest Raspian Lite on an RPi4.

The goal is to do something (i.e. elaborate them) with those samples in real-time. I *don't want* to send the elaborated samples to the output device again. I'm just asking how to "intercept" them before they reach the output device.

Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Sounds like this might be what you're looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/1194750/how-to-record-the-audio-output-on-raspbian

Comment: I've edited your question to hopefully make it more clear. To directly answer your question: no, I don't see any way that `cat` could ever give you audio samples. However, you may be able to record audio on the output device (using the method I linked in the comment above) and then read the data with your favorite software/library/python package/etc.

Comment: @PatrickCook, sorry but my question was more clear before. I *don't want to record*. I actually want to *retrieve samples* in order to process them in /real-time/.